# Getting values from a Python dictionary that has set objects for keys

Tags: python, dictionary, set, key

I'm using a python package that outputs a dictionary that has set objects as it's keys. I understand how to use the .get() method to get values from a dictionary normally but I don't understand how to reference a key that is a set object. 
I get this as my output from the package's function that I'm using:

```
{set(['a']):0.46835443038; set(['c']):0.303797468354; set(['a', 'b']):0.151898734177; set(['c', 'b']):0.0759493670886}
```

When I try to get the value 0.46835443038 using `dict_name.get("set(['a'])")`, it doesn't work. I've tried just `dict_name.get("a")` as well but no luck. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't have a set object as a key. What package is this? Also, you have semicolons as your dictionary delimiter, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: How the *heck* did you manage to get a dictionary with sets, an **unhashable** type,  as keys?

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you really can't use unhashable sets as dictionary keys in Python. However, if you're getting the output as a string from another program then you could extract the keys and values from the string using Regex (though you definitely should think of a better way to represent the keys):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "{set(['a']):0.46835443038; set(['c']):0.303797468354; set(['a', 'b']):0.151898734177; set(['c', 'b']):0.0759493670886}"

>>> new_dict = dict((key, float(val)) for key, val in re.findall("(set\(.+?\))\:(.+?)[;}]", text))
>>> print(new_dict)
>>> {"set(['a', 'b'])": 0.151898734177, "set(['a'])": 0.46835443038, "set(['c', 'b'])": 0.0759493670886, "set(['c'])": 0.303797468354}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > "*a dictionary has set objects as it's keys*"

With due respect, no, it doesn't. `set` isn't an allowable type to use as a `dict` key. `dict` keys must be hashable and therefore must be immutable. `set`s are mutuable, and therefore not hashable.

> > I don't understand how to reference a key that is a set object

If it *were* possible, here are some ways to reference the value:

```
v = dict_name.get(set(['a']))
v = dict_name[set(['a'])]
for k,v in dict_name.items():
    print(k,v)
for k in dict_name.keys():
    print(k, dict_name[k])
```